# \Yii::$app->request->isAjax not working in functional tests

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, functional-testing, codeception

I don't know if my way of doing functional tests is wrong - im just starting with it.

I have a controller action `update-ajax` and in there is a check like this

```php
public function actionUpdateAjax($id)
{
    //...
    $doc = $this->findDocument($id);
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $form->load($post) {
        $form->doSomething;
        $form->save();
        return $this->asJson(['success' => 1]);
    }
    //...
}
```

I have a `WorkflowCest` functional testcase like this:

```php
public function testUpdateAjaxValidUser(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $user = $I->grabFixture('user', 'user1');
    $I->amLoggedInAs($user);
    $doc = $I->grabFixture('docs', 'doc1');
    $I->sendAjaxPostRequest(['update-ajax', 'id' => $doc->id], ['Document[title]' => 'myNewTitle']);
    $I->canSeeRecord(Document::class, ['id' => $doc->id, 'title' => 'myNewTitle']);
}
```

This test pass when I remove the `isAjax` condition. But I can't remove this test for now...

In debug output there are no headers shown. And the `isAjax` function checks for the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. I read that the function `$I->haveHttpHeader` only works in acceptance tests. Is that true? Do I require at least the PhpBrowser?

So am I not able to do this test as a (much faster) functional test?
In that case am I not able to do functional tests if an action ist listening to specific headers?

*Edit:*

I tried to enable the PhpBrowser too but it sems i configured it wrong. This ist my functional.suite.yml

```yml
class_name: FunctionalTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - Yii2
            - PhpBrowser:
                url: 'http://localhost'
```

and this my codeception.yml in frontend:

```yml
namespace: frontend\tests
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            transaction: false
            configFile: 'config/test-local.php'
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - components/*
        - controllers/*
        - models/*
        - modules/*
```

Then the following error appears:

> [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConflictException]
>   Yii2 module conflicts with PhpBrowser
>
> > This usually happens when you enable two modules with the same actions
> >     but with different backends.     For instance, you can't run
> >     PhpBrowser, WebDriver, Laravel5 modules in one suite,
> >     as they implement similar methods but use different drivers to execute
> >     them.                            You can load a part of module (like:
> >     ORM) to avoid conflict.

How to do it right?

Thank you in adnvance.

Comment: Yes, you can use haveHttpHeader method in Yii tests: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2#haveHttpHeader

Comment: But only when PhpBrowser is enabled (i didn't get that working) or in acceptance tests. When im using this method the headers aren't recognized by the application.

Comment: Then it is a bug of Yii2 module.